# Visual Studio Enterprise from University

Tags: visual-studio-2015, licensing

I can get Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, thanks to my university from Microsoft Image. I was wondering if there are any limitations on the licence of what I can do with this version even after I stop being a student ?

At the moment I only want to use it for some personal projects and learning, but it would be nice if I could also use it for some freelance in the future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. **[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)** for details and the **[help]** for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean Microsoft Imagine?

If yes, it seems that there is no difference between the official versions of the program and the Imagine versions and according to the [FAQ](https://catalog.imagine.microsoft.com/en-us/support/faq) you can use it the same. Be sure to read the rest of the [Licence Agreement](https://catalog.imagine.microsoft.com/en-us/about/LicenseAgreement) but as far as I can tell you can use the products the same way that you would if you purchased it. I'll just quote summaries from the FAQ:

> **How may I use the Microsoft tools I get via Microsoft Imagine?**
>
> Feel free to use the tools and software from Microsoft Imagine to get ahead in school, develop new skills and take steps in research in science, technology, engineering or mathematics. Please review the license agreement for more details.
>
> **What is the difference between the Microsoft software from Microsoft Imagine and the products I can get online?**
>
> Nothing! Microsoft Imagine offers the same completely loaded Microsoft software that professional developers pay good cash to purchase. However, through Microsoft Imagine, we’re providing this software directly to students like you at no charge, to advance your skills through technical design, technology, math, science and engineering software, tools and training.

Just take note of this section in the Licence Agreement:

> **9. Ending the Subscription**
>   Once you no longer meet the eligibility criteria for the Subscription as defined under section 1 of this Agreement, your access to certain Subscription Benefits that require *annual* verification of eligibility will terminate as of the date of nonrenewal. However, Microsoft may terminate your Subscription or access to any Subscription Benefits at any time, with or without notice to you, in the event of a material violation of the Agreement, including all use rights associated with any software and any rights granted under Section 2 of the Agreement.

Some subscriptions can end immediately but it seems like Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise expires in 36 months after you entered your Imagine product key unfortunately. Well that's according to the [pricing](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/) of Visual Studio 2015 page

> 36 months (other Volume Licensing programs)